# memory error in pickle for a file of 37 bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

**Sample code:**

```
pfile=open("main.txt","rb")
size=os.stat("main.txt")
print(size.st_size)
records=pickle.load(pfile)
pfile.close()
```

I tried to run this code but it ended up giving a **memory error** ,
size of the file is 37 bytes only.

**After creating the file in binary mode i made some changes in it manually after which this error start coming.**

**Error window:**

```
37
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\apne py pr\startn games\spac inv startn.py", line 693, in <module>
    chkpwd()
  File "D:\Programming\apne py pr\startn games\spac inv startn.py", line 631, in chkpwd
    records=pickle.load(pfile)
MemoryError
```

Please explain why that happened.

Edit 1: The whole chunk of code.

```
def chkpwd():
     global password
     try:
          pfile=open("main.txt","rb")
          size=os.stat("main.txt")
          print(size.st_size)
          pickletools.dis(pfile)
          records=pickle.load(pfile)
          pfile.close()
          if len(records)>0:
               password=records[0]
               try:
                    con=msc.connect(user="root",host="localhost",passwd=password)
                    con.close()
                    __main__()
               except:
                    os.remove("main.txt")
                    chkpwd()
     except (FileNotFoundError , EOFError):
          pfile=open("main.txt","wb")
          def lenchk():
               global password
               if len(tp.get())>0:
                    z.append(tp.get())
                    password=tp.get()
                    pickle.dump([password],pfile)
                    pfile.close()
                    pcont.destroy()
               else:
                    pcont.destroy()
                    messagebox.showinfo("","Enter your MySQL Password")
                    chkpwd()
          z=[]
          pcont=Tk()
          pcont.geometry("450x240+300+300")
          pcont.config(bg="#bdffdb")
          pcont.overrideredirect(True)
          lp=Label(pcont,text="Enter PASSWORD of your \nMySQL Server",bg="#bdffdb",fg="black",font="courier 23 bold")
          bp=Button(pcont,width=3,text="OK",pady=-1,command=lenchk,bg='white',fg="black",font="courier 22 bold",bd=4)
          tp=Entry(pcont,width=14,bg='white',fg="black",font="courier 22 bold",bd=4,show="*")
          close_it(pcont)
          lp.place(x=15,y=54)
          tp.place(x=40,y=157)
          bp.place(x=330,y=146)
          pcont.mainloop()
          if len(z)>0:
               try:
                    con=msc.connect(user="root",host="localhost",passwd=password)
                    cur=con.cursor()
                    q="create database if not exists inv"
                    cur.execute(q)
                    con.commit()
                    q="use inv"
                    cur.execute(q)
                    con.commit()
                    q="create table if not exists invaders(name varchar(15) primary key,lv_1 int,lv_2 int)"
                    cur.execute(q)
                    con.commit()
                    con.close()
                    __main__()
               except :
                    messagebox.showerror(""," Wrong Password ")
                    os.remove("main.txt")
                    chkpwd()
          else:
               pfile.close()
               os.remove("main.txt")
```

Edit 2: passing through pickletools.dis()

```
37
    0: \x80 PROTO      4
    2: \x95 FRAME      2314885530818453519
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\apne py pr\startn games\spac inv startn.py", line 695, in <module>
    chkpwd()
  File "D:\Programming\apne py pr\startn games\spac inv startn.py", line 632, in chkpwd
    pickletools.dis(pfile)
  File "C:\Users\Anush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pickletools.py", line 2448, in dis
    for opcode, arg, pos in genops(pickle):
  File "C:\Users\Anush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pickletools.py", line 2285, in _genops
    raise ValueError("at position %s, opcode %r unknown" % (
ValueError: at position 11, opcode b' ' unknown
```

Comment: I think the more interesting part is, what kind of "manual changes" you did

Comment: @user8408080 i just add some space bars randomly.

Comment: Can you undo these modifications and see if the file can be opened again?

Comment: @user8408080 I Just didn't remember where i did. But yeah before that everything was running  smoothly.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you destroyed the file by adding characters in random positions and I guess the only way to solve this is to undo the changes

Comment: After opening the file, pass the file object to `pickletools.dis()` and show us the output. It's impossible for anyone to guess from what you've said. Note that pickles are emphatically **not** intended to be edited by hand.

Comment: @TimPeters I edited it by my hand adding some space randomly. But why this error and i am editing the ques for the result from pickletools.dis().

Comment: The `dis()` output shows that the random edits you made caused the pickle to request 2314885530818453519 bytes for a "frame" object to use internally. That's why you got a `MemoryError`: there isn't a machine in the universe with enough memory to create an object that big. The hex representation of that is 0x202020202020200f, and 0x20 is the ASCII code for a space character. You filled the pickle with garbage characters, and "garbage in, garbage out" is how many things in computers work.

Comment: @TimPeters Ok thanks for the explanation. So is there anyway i can code to remove garbage entered by user just before loading the file?

Comment: @TimPeters I think I can do it with the help of try and except ! Thanks for your time.